# Multiple ng-disabled parameters not working in AngularJS view - using && (and) and || (or)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hope you guys can help me.

I think it should be an easy solution, and I have tried multiple methods (options in brackets etc.), but just cant get both parameters to work.

When I use a single parameter it works fine.

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**
If my first drop down field's selection is either Week or Month, the next drop down filed must be enabled.

Like I mentioned; it does work with a single parameter. Example:

```
ng-disabled="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyType != Enum.ReportFrequency.Monthly"
```

But when I put an || (or) in the mix, it is not working at all:

```
ng-disabled="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyType != Enum.ReportFrequency.Monthly || reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyType != Enum.ReportFrequency.Weekly"
```

**Here are my 2 drop down fields in my view:**

```
<!-- Frequency -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Frequency</label>
        <div class="input-dropdown">
            <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Frequency"
                            ng-model="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName"
                            ng-options="reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencyNames"
                            ng-change="frequencyChanged()"
                            cc-fields="ReportFrequencyName"
                            cc-key-field="ReportFrequencyId"
                            cc-allow-search="reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencyNames != null && reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencyNames.length > 5"
                            name="iFrequencyName">
            </cc-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Frequency Options</label>
        <div class="input-dropdown">
            <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Frequency Option"
                            ng-model="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencySelectionName"
                            ng-options="reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencySelectionNames"
                            ng-disabled="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyType != Enum.ReportFrequency.Monthly || reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyType != Enum.ReportFrequency.Weekly"
                            cc-fields="ReportFrequencySelectionName"
                            cc-key-field="ReportFrequencySelectionId"
                            cc-allow-search="true"
                            name="iFrequencySelections">
            </cc-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why the down vote? I did research, and tried multiple methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Herewith the answer after some more research and assistance.

**I simply changed the || (or) operator to the && (and) operator.**

```
ng-disabled="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyType != Enum.ReportFrequency.Weekly && reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyType != Enum.ReportFrequency.Monthly"
```

Logically (one would think), the || should have worked, as I am basically saying:

> 'Enable the field when "this" or "that"'

But because I am using NOT (!=) to evaluate the validity of both my conditions, and `ng-disabled` as the directive, the opposite is true (I know, this is where I went down the rabbit hole!).

**In other words;**

> 'Disable the field when it is "not this" and "not that"'

(this is how I am making sense of it - and if I am wrong, please help me!).

**Here is some light reading to understand the concept and use of || and && better:**

I love this little explanation:

> JavaScript will short-circuit the evaluation the moment it knows when
>   a condition will be True or False.

http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2789-be-careful-with-compound-conditions-in-angularjs-and-javascript-in-general.htm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators